# My views are going out on when device resolution changes in react native

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application in there I have codded a screen like this.

```
 <View style={styles.patientView}>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.patientContainer,
          {height: (dimensions.window.height * 2.9) / 4},
        ]}>
        <AppText styles={styles.patientFormTitle}>
          {strings('new-patient.form-title')}
        </AppText>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <NewPatientForm
            navigate={() => _privacyNavigate(props.navigation)}
            onpress={_onPress}
            mobileNo={props.mobileNo}
            loadding={props.loadding}
            createpa={props.createpatient}
            location={location}
          />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.hr} />
      <View style={styles.patientBottomContainer}>
        <View style={styles.patientBottomView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _navigate(props.navigation)}>
            <AppText styles={styles.bottomLinkText}>
              {strings('new-patient.bottom-link')}
            </AppText>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

This is my new patient form code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-community/picker';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
import styles from './newpatientstyles';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {patientActions} from '_store/actions';
import {strings} from '_translations/i18n';
import AppText from '_components/appText';
import spinner from '_assets/img/spinner.gif';

const NewPatient = (props) => {
  const {navigate, mobileNo, onpress, loadding, createpa, location} = props;
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
          address: '',
          age: '',
          gender: '',
          mobileNo: mobileNo,
          privacy: false,
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          firstname: Yup.string().required(strings('new-patient.f-validation')),
          lastname: Yup.string().required(strings('new-patient.l-validation')),
          address: Yup.string().required(strings('new-patient.a-validation')),
          age: Yup.string().required(strings('new-patient.ag-valiation')),
          gender: Yup.string().required(strings('new-patient.g-validation')),
          mobileNo: Yup.string()
            .min(10, strings('new-patient.m-validation'))
            .required(strings('new-patient.m-validation')),
          privacy: Yup.boolean().oneOf(
            [true],
            strings('new-patient.privacy-validation'),
          ),
        })}
        enableReinitialize={mobileNo}
        onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
          onpress(values, createpa, location);
          setTimeout(() => {
            formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 500);
        }}>
        {(formprops) => (
          <View>
            <View
              style={
                !formprops.values.firstname && !formprops.errors.firstname
                  ? styles.inputView
                  : formprops.values.firstname &&
                    !formprops.errors.firstname &&
                    formprops.touched.firstname
                  ? styles.validInputView
                  : formprops.errors.firstname && formprops.touched.firstname
                  ? styles.inputViewError
                  : styles.inputView
              }>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                placeholder={strings('new-patient.f-placeholder')}
                placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                value={formprops.values.firstname}
                onChangeText={formprops.handleChange('firstname')}
                onBlur={formprops.handleBlur('firstname')}
                keyboardType="default"
              />
              {formprops.errors.firstname && formprops.touched.firstname ? (
                <Icon name="times" size={20} style={styles.errorIcon} />
              ) : null}
              {!formprops.errors.firstname &&
              formprops.values.firstname &&
              formprops.touched.firstname ? (
                <Icon name="check" size={20} style={styles.validIcon} />
              ) : null}
            </View>
            {formprops.touched.firstname && formprops.errors.firstname ? (
              <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                  {formprops.errors.firstname}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            ) : null}
            <View
              style={
                !formprops.values.lastname && !formprops.errors.lastname
                  ? styles.inputView
                  : formprops.values.lastname &&
                    !formprops.errors.lastname &&
                    formprops.touched.lastname
                  ? styles.validInputView
                  : formprops.errors.lastname && formprops.touched.lastname
                  ? styles.inputViewError
                  : styles.inputView
              }>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                placeholder={strings('new-patient.l-placeholder')}
                placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                value={formprops.values.lastname}
                onChangeText={formprops.handleChange('lastname')}
                onBlur={formprops.handleBlur('lastname')}
                keyboardType="default"
              />
              {formprops.errors.lastname && formprops.touched.lastname ? (
                <Icon name="times" size={20} style={styles.errorIcon} />
              ) : null}
              {!formprops.errors.lastname &&
              formprops.values.lastname &&
              formprops.touched.lastname ? (
                <Icon name="check" size={20} style={styles.validIcon} />
              ) : null}
            </View>
            {formprops.touched.lastname && formprops.errors.lastname ? (
              <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                  {formprops.errors.lastname}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            ) : null}
            <View
              style={
                !formprops.values.address && !formprops.errors.address
                  ? styles.inputView
                  : formprops.values.address &&
                    !formprops.errors.address &&
                    formprops.touched.address
                  ? styles.validInputView
                  : formprops.errors.address && formprops.touched.address
                  ? styles.inputViewError
                  : styles.inputView
              }>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                placeholder={strings('new-patient.ad-placeholder')}
                placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                value={formprops.values.address}
                onChangeText={formprops.handleChange('address')}
                onBlur={formprops.handleBlur('address')}
                keyboardType="default"
              />
              {formprops.errors.address && formprops.touched.address ? (
                <Icon name="times" size={20} style={styles.errorIcon} />
              ) : null}
              {!formprops.errors.address &&
              formprops.values.address &&
              formprops.touched.address ? (
                <Icon name="check" size={20} style={styles.validIcon} />
              ) : null}
            </View>
            {formprops.touched.address && formprops.errors.address ? (
              <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                  {formprops.errors.address}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            ) : null}
            <View
              style={
                !formprops.values.age && !formprops.errors.age
                  ? styles.inputView
                  : formprops.values.age &&
                    !formprops.errors.age &&
                    formprops.touched.age
                  ? styles.validInputView
                  : formprops.errors.age && formprops.touched.age
                  ? styles.inputViewError
                  : styles.inputView
              }>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                placeholder={strings('new-patient.a-placeholder')}
                placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                value={formprops.values.age}
                onChangeText={formprops.handleChange('age')}
                onBlur={formprops.handleBlur('age')}
                keyboardType="numeric"
              />
              {formprops.errors.age && formprops.touched.age ? (
                <Icon name="times" size={20} style={styles.errorIcon} />
              ) : null}
              {!formprops.errors.age &&
              formprops.values.age &&
              formprops.touched.age ? (
                <Icon name="check" size={20} style={styles.validIcon} />
              ) : null}
            </View>
            {formprops.touched.age && formprops.errors.age ? (
              <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                  {formprops.errors.age}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            ) : null}
            <View
              style={
                !formprops.values.gender
                  ? styles.inputView
                  : styles.validInputView
              }>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={formprops.values.gender}
                style={styles.picker}
                mode="dropdown"
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                  formprops.setFieldValue('gender', itemValue)
                }>
                <Picker.Item
                  label={strings('new-patient.s-placeholder')}
                  value="0"
                  color="#bbbbbb"
                />
                <Picker.Item
                  label={strings('new-patient.male')}
                  value={strings('new-patient.male')}
                />
                <Picker.Item
                  label={strings('new-patient.female')}
                  value={strings('new-patient.female')}
                />
              </Picker>
              {formprops.errors.gender && formprops.touched.gender ? (
                <Icon name="times" size={20} style={styles.errorIcon} />
              ) : null}
              {!formprops.errors.gender &&
              formprops.values.gender &&
              formprops.touched.gender ? (
                <Icon name="check" size={20} style={styles.validIcon} />
              ) : null}
            </View>
            <View
              style={
                !formprops.values.mobileNo && !formprops.errors.mobileNo
                  ? styles.inputView
                  : formprops.values.mobileNo && !formprops.errors.mobileNo
                  ? styles.validInputView
                  : styles.inputViewError
              }>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                placeholder={strings('new-patient.mobileNo')}
                placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                value={formprops.values.mobileNo}
                onChangeText={formprops.handleChange('mobileNo')}
                onBlur={formprops.handleBlur('mobileNo')}
                keyboardType="numeric"
              />
              {formprops.touched.mobileNo && formprops.errors.mobileNo ? (
                <Icon name="times" size={20} style={styles.errorIcon} />
              ) : null}
              {formprops.values.mobileNo && !formprops.errors.mobileNo ? (
                <Icon name="check" size={20} style={styles.validIcon} />
              ) : null}
            </View>
            {formprops.touched.mobileNo && formprops.errors.mobileNo ? (
              <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                  {formprops.errors.mobileNo}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            ) : null}
            <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
              <CheckBox
                tintColors={{true: '#007aff', false: '#007aff'}}
                value={formprops.values.privacy}
                onValueChange={(value) =>
                  formprops.setFieldValue('privacy', value)
                }
              />
              <AppText styles={styles.termsText}>
                {strings('new-patient.privacy-text')}
              </AppText>
              <View style={styles.termsLinkView}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigate}>
                  <AppText styles={styles.termsLink}>
                    {' '}
                    {strings('new-patient.privacy-link')}
                  </AppText>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
            {formprops.touched.privacy && formprops.errors.privacy ? (
              <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                  {formprops.errors.privacy}
                </AppText>
              </View>
            ) : null}

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.sendButton}
              onPress={formprops.handleSubmit}>
              {loadding ? (
                <Image source={spinner} style={styles.bimage} />
              ) : (
                <AppText styles={styles.sendButtonText}>
                  {strings('new-patient.btn-text')}
                </AppText>
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default NewPatient;
```

this is my stylings

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  patientView: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  patientTitleView: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: '5%',
  },
  patientTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
  },
  patientFormTitle: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '200',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  hr: {
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 5,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
    borderBottomWidth: 2.0,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
  },
  patientBottomContainer: {
    height: 50,
  },
  patientBottomView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  patientBottomContainerText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#444444',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  formContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
  },
  patientBottomLinkView: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  patientBottomContainerTextView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    paddingLeft: 30,
  },
  bottomLinkText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#484848',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
  },
  errorMessage: {},
  errorMessageText: {
    color: '#ff3d3d',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  patientContainer: {
    marginTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    elevation: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 3},
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,
  },
  submitButtonView: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  patienterrorInput: {
    marginTop: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#ff3d3d',
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  inputView: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  inputViewError: {
    // flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#ff3d3d',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  validInputView: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#007aff',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  errorIcon: {
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#ff3d3d',
  },
  validIcon: {
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#007aff',
  },
  textField: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    paddingLeft: 0,
  },
  picker: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    letterSpacing: 2,
    marginLeft: -5,
  },
  checkBoxContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  termsText: {
    color: '#888888',
    fontWeight: '500',
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  termsLink: {
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#222222',
    fontSize: 15,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
    borderBottomWidth: 2.0,
  },
  termsLinkView: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  sendButton: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#007aff',
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginTop: 25,
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sendButtonText: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    letterSpacing: 2,
  },
  bimage: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
});

export default styles;
```

I have given height to middle view according to device height. So when resolution changes on some devices bottom view is going out of the screen. So can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height of the view doesn't prevent it from expanding when things like margin values make the View component taller or wider.
You can set all the margins in percentage so that they can adapt themselves with the device dimensions.